# How to configure PHP coding rules in netbeans 7.4

Tags: php, netbeans

I recognized that there are new hints in Netbeans 7.4 for PHP coding.

For example there is a *"Too Many Lines"* hint which says:

> Method Length is 115 Lines (10 allowed)

Another hint is:

> Too Many Nested Blocks in Function Declaration.

I found out that I can disable each Hint under: `Tools > Options > Editor > Hints > PHP`.

But I don't want to disable the `Too Many Lines` Hint completely. What I want to do is to configure the IDE to allow 100 lines instead of 10. Is there a way to set the coding rules?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It's quite simple, and I bet you'll laugh about the solution. The default NetBeans Preferences window just *hides* the option based on window size. Just stretch out the window widely and you'll see that there's actually a input to change the default value from 10 to whatever you want :)

[image: Enlarged]

Comment: oh man. instead of laughing i choose to bang my head on the table.

Comment: Yeah, NetBeans has the bad habit of doing that to people.