# Netbeans says PHP function has too many lines

Tags: php, netbeans

I have a function and netbeans is saying I can only have 20 lines in my code.
Why is this and how could I fix this. I have another function with the same problem. Dreamweaver doesn't say anything so I don't know if this is a big problem.

my code:

```
function dispalyEvent($weekNr, $week, $year){
    echo "<p>";
    $gendate = new DateTime();
    $gendate->setISODate($year,$week,$weekNr);

    $month = $gendate->format('m');
    $day =  $gendate->format('d');
    $event_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendar ORDER BY starttime"); 

    while($event = mysql_fetch_array($event_query)) { 
    $startYear = $event['startyear'];
    $startMonth = $event['startmonth'];
    $startDay = $event['startdate'];
    $endYear = $event['endyear'];
    $endMonth = $event['endmonth'];
    $endDay = $event['enddate'];

    $period = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime($startYear.$startMonth.$startDay),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime($endYear.$endMonth.$endDay +1)
    );

     $currentDate = $year."-".$month."-".$day;

    foreach ($period as $savedDate) {   

    if ($currentDate == $savedDate->format('Y-m-d')){
        if ($event['Approved'] == "Approved"){

      echo "</p>";
      echo "<p>";
         if ($event['ad']) {
        echo "<img src='images/".$event['ad']."' alt='event-ad' width='300' height='100' />";
         } else { echo "&nbsp;"; } 
      echo "</p>";
      echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
      echo "<div class='toggleLink' style='cursor: pointer; color: #333;'>";
         echo $event['starttime']."  ".$event['title']; 
        echo "</p>";
      echo "</div>";
     echo " <div class='toggle'>";
        echo "<p class='toggleLink'>";
         echo "(".$event['starttime']."-".$event['endtime'].") ".$event['location']." - ".$event['address']." - Admission Price: $".$event['price']."<br>".$event['description'];
        echo "</div>";
        }}}}
        echo "</p>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: just smelly code..possbile duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768531/how-to-configure-php-coding-rules-in-netbeans-7-4

Comment: PHP will still run with more than 20 lines in a function, but having exceptionally long functions in your code is considered bad coding practise.... NetBeans is trying to help make you a better coder by giving you hints like this, while Dreamweaver doesn't give a monkeys cuss if you're a good coder or not, as long as you've purchased a valid license